# Do ruby modules have constructors?

Tags: ruby, constructor, module, mixins

Something that is called when it is extended.

Eg. this piece of code:

```
module M
  def init(x)
    @x = 5
    self
  end
  def foo
    super
    puts @x
  end
end
class D
  def foo
    puts 1
  end
end

D.new.extend(M).init(5).foo
```

works and returns 1 5. But I want to change the last line to read

```
D.new.extend(M.init(5)).foo
```

or better yet

```
D.new.extend(M(5)).foo
```

to prevent bugs from not setting @x.

On a similar note, can I say something like

```
class X
  include Debug(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by having a method that returns a Module.

```
def M(par)
  m = Module.new
  m.module_eval %Q{
    def foo
      super
      puts #{par}
    end
  }
  m
end

D.new.extend(M(5)).foo # => 5

class X
  include M(4)
end

X.new.foo # => 4
```

Comment: This will make editing the module a pain though. Is there any way to do this inside the module itself? 
eg. module M;
  def self.init(x);
    new_mod = M;
    #do something to new_mod here;
    new_mod;
  end;
end;

Comment: Well you can take the above method and use it only to create methods that need this kind of treatment. So instead of `Module.new` you could call `module_eval` on some existing module you wrote before. But to answer your question directly: No, modules do not have constructors.